# Hilbert-Schmidt operators and Trace-class operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Hilbert-Schmidt operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ are linear operators $T\in B(\mathcal H)$ such that $$\|T\|_2=\Big(\sum_{\alpha\in I}\|Te_\alpha\|^2\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty$$ 
Trace-class operators are defined as $T\in B(\mathcal H)$ such $$\|T\|_1=\sum_{\alpha\in I}\left<|T|e_\alpha,e_\alpha\right> <\infty$$ Both $B_2(\mathcal H)$ and $B_1(\mathcal H)$ form Banach $*$-algebras with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ norms, respectively. 
I was wondering why they don't form a $C^*$-algebra? Is the $C^*$-identity not satisfied? If so, then please give an explicit example.

What about when $\mathcal H$ is finite-dimensional? I guess in this cases both $B_1(\mathcal H)$ and $B_2(\mathcal H)$ will form a $C^*$-algebra, but can't prove it.

Comment: Is $I$ the set of indices for the orthonormal basis of $\mathcal H$?

Comment: The norm doesn't satisfy $\|T^* T\| = \|T\|^2$ for example when $T$ is normal compact $T \sum_j u_j = \sum_j c_j u_j$ for some orthonormal basis $(u_j)$ then $\|T\|_r = (\sum_j |c_j|^r)^{1/r}, \|T^*T\|_r =  (\sum_j |c_j|^{2r})^{1/r}$

Comment: @niki di giano yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases you are looking for a positive operator $T$ such that $\operatorname{Tr}(T^2)\ne\operatorname{Tr}(T)^2$. Those are plenty. For instance take 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $\operatorname{Tr}(T^2)=5$, while $\operatorname{Tr}(T)^2=9$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works!